# Validate errors with LinqToSql (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to use `LinqToSql` in Visual Studio 2010(Asp.net, C#).
The insert/delete/update records works just fine but if I write letters in a `int` field, the program breaks in a non-pretty way.

In my `DataClasses.Designer` I have:

```
partial void Insertproduct(product instance);
```

and I add other class with:

```
public partial class product
{

    partial void OnPriceChanging(string value)
    {
        Regex Price = new Regex("^[A-Z0-9 a-z]*$");
        if (Precio.IsMatch(value) == false)
        {
            throw new Exception("Just numbers");
        }
    }

}
```

I don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use int.TryParse it will return a 0 if the string cannot be converted to an int.

```
int number;
bool IsNumber = int.TryParse("someString", out number);
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression you have used is not correct for validating 'only numbers'. Use this:

```
public partial class Product
{

    partial void OnPriceChanging(string value)
    {
        Regex price = new Regex("^[0-9]*$");
        if (!price.IsMatch(value))
        {
            throw new Exception("Just numbers");
        }
    }

}
```